# Sort cProfile output by percall when profiling a Python script

Tags: python, profiling, cprofile

I'm using `python -m cProfile -s calls myscript.py`

`python -m cProfile -s percall myscript.py` does not work.

The Python documentation says "Look in the Stats documentation for valid sort values.": http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#module-cProfile, which I cannot find.

Comment: Also have a look at snakeviz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593019/is-there-any-simple-way-to-benchmark-python-script/59772322#59772322

Comment: There's a patch for this which is being ignored unfortunately: https://bugs.python.org/issue18795

Answer (score 151, accepted):

-s only uses [the keys found under sort_stats.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#pstats.Stats.sort_stats)

```
calls (call count)
cumulative (cumulative time)
cumtime (cumulative time)
file (file name)
filename (file name)
module (file name)
ncalls (call count)
pcalls (primitive call count)
line (line number)
name (function name)
nfl (name/file/line)
stdname (standard name)
time (internal time)
tottime (internal time)
```

Here's an example

```
python -m cProfile -s tottime myscript.py
```

Comment: Just to clear it up, for noobs like me, you don't use the quotes :)  So an example to sort methods by time spent in the method is "python -m cProfile -s tottime myscript.py"

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using quotes (at least in bash), is there? The quotes are eaten by bash command preprocessing..

Comment: As far as windows is concerned, one cannot use the quotes. Also to be noted - sort by time and tottime is one and the same thing.

Comment: I want to be able to sort the cprofile output by any of the columns provided. As far as I know, currently it is still not possible to sort it by the column labeled `percall`.

Comment: What is the percall column? You are able to sort on any column. https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#pstats.Stats.sort_stats As a last resort you could use the index of the column`For backward-compatibility reasons, the numeric arguments -1, 0, 1, and 2 are permitted.`

Comment: @JoshuaOlson your link to the docs.python makes no mention of sorting by percall. It seems odd to me that even though the percall is the most useful sorting column, yet it is not implemented.

Comment: I suspect it isn't included because it is a hybrid/derived metric. This seems like a straightforward thing to be able to add. And python is always happy to accept new features if you want to submit a pull request. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/pstats.py

Comment: Yes it's computed in `Stats.print_line` of `pstats.py`, which prints the information after it has been sorted. But you could also just write your own primitive printer: an instance of `Stats` has a `dict()` in the `.stats` field where the keys are function names. After looking at `_lsprof.c` it seems the values in the `dict()` are tuples of: (<num calls>, <num calls including recursive calls>, <time spent in call including subcalls>, <time spent in call excluding subcalls>, <what called this>).