# Benchmarking run times in Python

Tags: python, benchmarking

I have to benchmark JSON serialization time and compare it to thrift  and Google's protocol buffer's serialization time. Also it has to be in Python.

I was planning on using the Python profilers.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Would the profiler be the best way to find function runtimes? Or would outputting a timestamp before and after the function call be the better option?

Or is there an even better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `profile` docs that you linked to:

> **Note** The profiler modules are designed to provide an execution profile for a given program, not for benchmarking purposes (for that, there is `timeit` for reasonably accurate results). This particularly applies to benchmarking Python code against C code: the profilers introduce overhead for Python code, but not for C-level functions, and so the C code would seem faster than any Python one.

So, no, you do not want to use `profile` to benchmark your code. What you want to use `profile` for is to figure out *why* your code is too slow, after you already know that it is.

And you do not want to output a timestamp before and after the function call, either. There are just way too many things you can get wrong that way if you're not careful (using the wrong timestamp function, letting the GC run a cycle collection in the middle of your test run, including test overhead in the loop timing, etc.), and `timeit` takes care of all of that for you.

Something like this is a common way to benchmark things:

```
for impl in 'mycode', 'googlecode', 'thriftcode':
    t = timeit.timeit('serialize(data)', 
                      setup='''from {} import serialize; 
                               with open('data.txt') as f: data=f.read()
                            '''.format(impl),
                      number=10000)
    print('{}: {}'.format(impl, t)
```

(I'm assuming here that you can write three modules that wrap the three different serialization tools in the same API, a single `serialize` function that takes a string and does something or other with it. Obviously there are different ways to organize things.)

Comment: Hey Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. The timeit module is perfect.  

I was going to run a bunch of data ONCE with the profiler.  The timeit function lets me run a little data ALOT of time which works perfect for these serialization packages because they only allow small chunks up to 1M of data to be serialized at one time.

The only problem now is how to compare them accurately. 
Google protocol buffer serializes using one method call while thrift serializes using three message calls with the first two setting up the memory space.

So I'm not sure how to accurately compare.

Comment: @Nickthemagicman: If you have to use the three method calls for each thrift serialization, then write a wrapper around all three method calls and it should be a fair comparison. If you have to use the first two calls only once to serialize a whole slew of things, make the first two calls part of the setup, and only time the third call.

Answer (score 2):

You should be careful when you are profiling python code based on a time stamp at the start and end of the problem. This does not take into account other processes that might also be running concurrently.

Instead, you should consider looking at

[Is there any simple way to benchmark python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593019/is-there-any-simple-way-to-benchmark-python-script)