# How do I get the time execution for each iteration? Python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
for times in range(50):
    factor = (min(getHeight(),getWidth()) / math.sqrt(qtdPosicoes)) * guess()
    positionInGrid = {}
    grid = np.zeros((getGridColumns(),getGridLines()))
    groupMatrix = np.zeros((grid.shape[0], grid.shape[1]))
    groups = getGroups(grid, listaComPosicoes, getXRanges(listaComPosicoes),getYRanges(listaComPosicoes))
    solution = calculaSilhueta()
    if bestSolution is None or solution > bestSolution:
       bestSolution = solution
```

I found in the documentation time module but I did not understand how to use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593019/is-there-any-simple-way-to-benchmark-python-script

Comment: Put the above in a function (with no loops) and look at the `timeit` module to do the timing/repeating for you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An easy way using this module is to get `time.time()` to mark the start of your code, and use `time.time()` again to mark the end of it. After that, substract the them so you can get the duration.

So your code should be like:

```
for times in range(50):
    start = time.time()
    #do some stuff
    stop = time.time()
    duration = stop-start
    print(duration)
```

Example:

```
>>> for i in range(3):
      start = time.time()
      print(i)
      stop = time.time()
      print(stop-start)


0
0.08444404602050781
1
0.014003992080688477
2
0.009001970291137695
```

But a better option would be to use the `timeit` module, which is even easier:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def myfunction(time):
      print(time)


>>> result = timeit.timeit("for i in range(2): myfunction(i)", setup="from __main__ import myfunction", number=1)
0
1
>>> result
0.0868431608504352
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is

```
start = time.time()
... do the computation ...
stop = time.time()
duration = stop - start
```