# Test which function is faster

Tags: python, performance, time

I have 3 functions that do the same thing but with a different implementation and I want to check which of them is faster.

I know that there is a timer library, but my concern is that if one of them is linear and the other one is exponential I have to make a few tests with different inputs to find the answer. For instance, if the input is a list, maybe the function A will be faster for list with length 20, but function B for length 1000.

So, I was wondering if there is any way to do this automatically. I could create a script to do this and maybe with a few plots with the time in base of the inputs length, but I don't want to invent the wheel again, if there is a library that can do this for me.

Comment: Maybe tell us the programming language you are using?

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is broken - could you at least mention the programming language?

Comment: Probably I need a coffee. I thought I added it on tags. I use Python.

Comment: I think it's a relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593019/is-there-any-simple-way-to-benchmark-python-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `timeit`:

```
import timeit

example = 'map(lambda x: x + 1, range(100000)'
t = timeit.Timer(example)
t.timeit()
```

If you want something more featureful, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593019/is-there-any-simple-way-to-benchmark-python-script) may be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

If the functions are simple, you can do something like this (with the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> a = ('A()', 'def A():\n    x = [i for i in range({list_length})]\n    x * 3')
>>> b = ('B()', 'def B():\n    x = []\n    for i in range({list_length}) * 3:\n        x.append(i)')
>>> c = ('C()', 'def C():\n    x = []\n    for i in range({list_length}):\n        x.append(i)\n    x * 3')
>>> for num in (100, 1000, 10000):
    for func in (a, b, c):
        print func[0], '=>', num,
        timeit.timeit(func[0], setup=func[1].format(list_length=num), number=10000)
```

The result:

```
A() => 100
0.06415607679355162
B() => 100
0.29436154161112427
C() => 100
0.11945218201799435
A() => 1000
0.4792028142351228
B() => 1000
2.701182674568372
C() => 1000
1.0364000362492334
A() => 10000
4.432893686294392
B() => 10000
26.445674297814094
C() => 10000
10.198394832984377
```

If the functions are more complex, I would suggest using a [Python Profiler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).