# What's the fastest way to obtain inverse of a float

Tags: python, optimization

I want to make a small optimization to a code that runs trillions of times. Which way of calculating the inverse of a float64 is faster?

So far, the ways I know of calculating the inverse are the following.

```
k = 3.788
result1 = k**-1
result2 = 1/k
```

I'd expect this question to be answered but searching **whats faster 1 divide or power of -1** on google (and similarly worded) returned `0` results. No exaggeration.

Comment: Did you try benchmarking it?

Comment: If you're planning to do anything trillions of times, working on single floats one by one in Python is not going to cut it no matter how you microoptimize individual operations. At the very least, you're going to have to use NumPy.

Comment: Even if you optimize a single operation, loop overhead in Python is huge - you may get thousands of times' worth of speedup by using native code to do the important loops - NumPy is a good option. Or Cython, if you really want to get as optimal as possible.

Comment: Even just the Python opcode dispatch is going to be several orders of magnitude whatever speedup you may obtain by changing the way you perform your floating point operation. This kind of optimization is completely pointless in such a language. _Edit_: oh I've been beaten to it by @RandomDavis

Comment: Or numba. If this is in a regular loop, numpy isn't going to help. In fact, it will probably be slower. So numba or cython in that case

Comment: Also, you don't obtain any result for your Google query because the `-` of `-1` is intended by Google as "does not contain 1", so you are performing a query that asks for documents containing `1` and not containing it, hence the zero results. You have to add double quotes around the `-1` to make it interpret literally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any simple way to benchmark python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593019/is-there-any-simple-way-to-benchmark-python-script)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I see I may have come off as lazy for not searching how to benchmark. I honestly thought it'd take more time to implement it than do a cursory search (and that should have been easy if I'd known of google's `-` operator.) Ended getting much more knowledge than I bargained for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a typical situation the best way to compute the inverse is as

```
y = 1.0 / k
```

This avoids any power computation (slower than a division) and any type conversion. Indeed, using IPython on my machine I have

```
In [1]: k = 3.788

In [2]: %%timeit
   ...: result1 = k**-1
57.8 ns ± 0.295 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [3]: %%timeit
   ...: result2 = 1/k
32 ns ± 0.197 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: result3 = 1.0/k
24.1 ns ± 0.177 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm also curious as to which one would be faster:`k**-1` or `k**-1.0`. I'd guess it depends on whether Python has two algorithms for integer exponents or not...

Comment: Just for the fun of it, I ran the same benchmark in [Julia](https://julialang.org/); there (as of interpreter 1.0.1), `k ^ -1` is much faster (0.039ns median) than `1 / k` (1.899ns median). Of course, both those numbers blow the doors of the Python values above... perhaps the OP might think about Julia for their project, if they're running trillions of values. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you would need to run the same benchmark in `ipython` to get `python` timings that are at all comparable--your machine is not @Marco's machine.

Comment: @HAL9001, on the same laptop where I collected the Julia numbers above, IPython 6.5.0 on Python 3.6 clocks 99.9ns for the first, 60ns for the second, 43ns for the third. So yes, my machine is not Marco's machine; it's *slower*, making the difference between Python and Julia even larger than it initially appeared.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I do not have Julia installed, but I would be curious to know what are your benchmarks if you do the same calculations with a very large array (using NumPy in Python, of course).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I just tried to set `k = numpy.random.normal(size=1000000)` and repeated the tests above. Interestingly, all timing for me are now approximately equivalent, regardless of the method used to compute the inverse (500µs, that is 0.5ns per element). Presumably Julia is going to be faster than that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thank you! Given the time you got earlier, I guess that approximately now Julia and Python + NumPy perform similarly.

Comment: *nod* -- with NumPy's optimized C implementations and Julia's optimizing compiler, it makes sense that they'd both be close to underlying hardware performance.