# Speed of del vs remove on list

Tags: python

Assume that I have a list, and I have an element that I want to remove from it. Now suppose I have the index of that element, and I also know exactly what element it is. Would it be faster to do `del myList[index]` or `myList.remove(element)`?

Comment: ... why not just [perform the benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593019/is-there-any-simple-way-to-benchmark-python-script) yourself...?

Comment: You can bet that `del` is faster. `remove()` has to find the element, *and* then delete it, practically with `del`.

Comment: If you are removing elements from a list so frequently that the difference would be noticeable, you should probably be using a different data structure anyway.

Comment: @tevemadar although, algorithmically, these are both the same

Comment: Just be sure you don't do either in a loop that's iterating over that list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is Python's List Implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917574/how-is-pythons-list-implemented)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga absolutely not, a CPython list is a flat array, you really index it directly. Also, `remove()` will remove the first matching element of the list. With `del` you can remove any.

Comment: @tevemadar so what? `del` and `remove` both require O(N) time. Merely *indexing* a list, i.e `mylist[idx]`, which will call `list.__getitem__` is constant time (because it is essentially a random-access lookup of an item in an underlying buffer). However, `del mylist[idx]`, which will call `list.__delitem__` still require O(N) time (at least, if you are "near the beginning") because *everything after that must move*. [This is a basic fact of the array list data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Complexity is not actual runtime.

Comment: @tevemadar did I ever claim, *anywhere* that "complexity is actual runtime"? I stated that *algorithmically*, i.e. their time complexity, is the same. And indeed runtime wise, these will be very, very similar in CPython.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga they can't be similar if one algorithm has to do a loop first, then execute the other algorithm completely. Removing the first element is practically the same for them, but removing the last one is N step longer than the absolutely 0 work required from the other. On average I would expect `remove()` being 50% slower than `del`.

Comment: @tevemadar yes, indeed, I agree that removing from the beginning will result in small differences, whereas removing from the end will result in large differences. However, the *average case* will still be O(N) for both, and both will suffer from polynomial behavior if done in a loop whose size will vary as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the index already, you'd use `del`.

Otherwise, `remove` first needs to traverse the list, find the (first) index for the element, then `del` it. This would, therefore, make it slower.

Comment: Does del need to traverse the list until the index, and then delete it, or does it work another way?

Comment: The main purpose for using a list is that `myList[index]` is an O(1) operation. There's no search involved.

Comment: Well, both resize the lists, so there is some overhead associated with that

Comment: @RyanFu both `.remove` and `del` will require O(N) time

Answer (score 1):

Without any knowledge on how `del` or `remove()` performs, we can write a test using the `timeit` library to determine which one is faster. In this example, I simulate using both methods 10,000 times and print the average time required:

```py
import timeit

num_runs = 10000

del_method = 'lst = [1, 2, 3]; del lst[i]'
del_setup = 'i = 0'
print(timeit.Timer(del_method, setup=del_setup).timeit(number=num_runs))

remove_method = 'lst = [1, 2, 3]; lst.remove(ele)'
remove_setup = 'ele = 1'
print(timeit.Timer(remove_method, setup=remove_setup).timeit(number=num_runs))
```

Ouput:

```
0.0005947000000000036
0.0007260000000000044
```

As we can see, `del` performs faster in this simple scenario. This makes sense knowing that `remove()` performs a search before removing the element. I can imagine with an even larger list the difference between the times would only grow.

Comment: Yes, but my point is that at these small sizes, these benchmarks are very misleading. note, `ele` is always the first element, so the time difference will actually *get smaller* as the list gets bigger, because *both* `del` and `remove` have to touch every element that comes after the element that is removed, and the cost of finding the first element stays the same, and the internal re-arranging starts to dominate the time it takes to perform both operations.\

Comment: And it's not a useless comment, it's a warning to anyone reading this not to extrapolate based on these test cases.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My comment was pointing out that stating something is useless and not providing evidence nor an argument does not help future readers. I would like to thank you for clarifying your claim, and I agree that the test case is not useful for all scenarios. I made sure to state in my original answer that this is a "simple scenario" and I never meant for it to be the one and only solution to this question. Ideally, anyone who reads my answer should write a test case for their own situation and move on from there.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: `del` **is remarkably faster than** `remove`.