# How to monitor for how much time each line of stdout was the last output line in Bash for benchmarking?

Tags: bash

For example, suppose I have the script:

```
(echo a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 3; echo c; sleep 2)
```

which outputs:

```
a
b
c
```

When running that script, possibly through a pipe, I would like to obtain something like:

```
1.00 a
3.00 b
2.00 c
```

because the line `a` was the last line of stdout for 1.00 seconds, before it was replaced by `b` as the last line.

I don't want to modify the program being run, and in my actual use case the stdout will be generated by a complex executable which I don't want to modify, e.g. QEMU booting the Linux kernel.

This would allow me to do a quick and dirty profiling of the program being  run, to determine what segment is taking the longest.

Comment: Just wrap your executable into one that gets its output and compute time spent in between two lines...

Answer (score 4):

If you're happy with a resolution of seconds, you can use this one-liner:

```
t=$SECONDS; (echo a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 3; echo c; sleep 2) | while read line; do echo $((SECONDS - t)) $line; t=$SECONDS; done
```

If you are OK with installing node.js, this is exactly what [gnomon](https://github.com/paypal/gnomon) does:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**moreutils `ts`**

I knew someone had written this before!

```
$ sudo apt-get install moreutils
$ (echo a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 3; echo c; sleep 2; echo d; sleep 1) | ts -i
00:00:00 a
00:00:01 b
00:00:03 c
00:00:02 d
$ (echo a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 3; echo c; sleep 2; echo d; sleep 1) | ts -i '%.s'
0.000010 a
0.983308 b
3.001129 c
2.001120 d
$ (echo a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 3; echo c; sleep 2; echo d; sleep 1) | ts -s
00:00:00 a
00:00:01 b
00:00:04 c
00:00:06 d   
$ (echo a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 3; echo c; sleep 2; echo d; sleep 1) | ts
Apr 13 03:10:44 a
Apr 13 03:10:45 b
Apr 13 03:10:48 c
Apr 13 03:10:50 d
```

If you Google instead for the related "add timestamp to stdout" there are many results:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26728/prepending-a-timestamp-to-each-line-of-output-from-a-command
- https://serverfault.com/questions/310098/how-to-add-a-timestamp-to-bash-script-log
- [Is there a Unix utility to prepend timestamps to stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21564/is-there-a-unix-utility-to-prepend-timestamps-to-stdin)

**Bash `while read`**

This gives it in millis:

```
stdouttime() (
  tp="$(date +%s%N)"
  while read line; do
    tc="$(date +%s%N)"
    echo $(((tc - tp) / 1000000))
    echo "$line"
    tp=$tc
  done
  tc="$(date +%s%N)";
  echo $(((tc - tp) / 1000000))
)
(echo a; sleep 1; echo b; sleep 3; echo c; sleep 2) | stdouttime
```

Sample output:

```
2
a
1000
b
3002
c
2002
```

Based on: https://serverfault.com/questions/151109/how-do-i-get-current-unix-time-in-milliseconds-using-bash

Comment: Good use of bash, without resorting to outside programs. Rather than tp and tc, which have no meaning, if you need to modify the script 2yrs from now, I would use 'begin' and 'end'. Additionally, I would append " millisecons" or " ms" to the output, to add context. Thanks for the reference to the other question.